# Applying CSS code to all pages (e.g. master page)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, css, content, webpart-width

1. I am working on SharePoint 365 (2013).
2. I saved code as a css file (exact code below)

**CSS**

```
/* Resize navigation fly-out width */
ul.dynamic {
  width: auto !important;  /* !important needed to override inline SharePoint style */
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

3. I saved css file in Style Library
4. I added content editor web part and pointed to the css file
5. The home page took the changes and allowed the width of the drop down menus to increase

---

My issue.  I am an extreme novice and have no idea how to make it "take" on all the other pages.  As soon as I navigate off the home page, I lose that width change and it look sterrible.

Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Apply CSS code to all pages , follow the mentioned steps below :

- Open Site > Site Settings .
- Below Look and Feel > Click on (Master Page) or Design Manager.

[image]

- At Site Master Page Settings > Scroll down till `Alternate CSS URL`
- Check `Specify a CSS file to be used by this site and all sites that inherit from it:`
- Browse to your CSS file
- Check  `Reset all subsites to inherit this alternate CSS URL`  if you need to apply CSS for all subsites.

[image]

Comment: @ErinA Glad to hear it's helped you , so Should you please set my answer as answer , it's the true  sign beside my answer ,  
also check http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to gain the informed badge